# QTableWidget with setItem does not shows data

Tags: c++, qt

i'm new with Qt and really need help with the Problem. I'm currently working on a Project for practical training at School. I'm getting stucked when i used ui->tableWidget->setItem(.....) but the things did not show. Although new rows is added with blank cells. 
I need help to spot the Problem and sorry for my poor english. Thanks

```
void TravelAgency::CreateBooking(char type, double price, string start, string end, long travelID, vector<string> bookingDetails)
{
.
.
.
.
ui->tableWidget->insertRow(ui->tableWidget->rowCount());
int a = ui->tableWidget->rowCount();
 QString s = QString::number(idnummer);
 ui->tableWidget->setItem(a,0, new QTableWidgetItem(s));
 s = QString::number(price);
 ui->tableWidget->setItem(a,1, new QTableWidgetItem(s));
 s = QString::number(travelID);
 ui->tableWidget->setItem(a,2, new QTableWidgetItem(s));
.
.
.
}
```

There are already some Data in my Table, these Data has shown perfectly with the same syntax. I have already debugged and make sure the values of these variable is correct. Somehow these data did now show.
With this method ,it's work:

```
   void TravelAgency::on_actionDatei_Einlesen_triggered()
    {
        ui->tableWidget->resizeColumnsToContents();       // resize columns to contents

        ui->tableWidget->clear();                         // clear all Data from Table
        ui->tableWidget->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers); // Read Only
        ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(0);   // Remove all rows
        ui->tableWidget->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QStringList()<<"Buchungsnummer"<<"Preis"<<"Name"<<"Reise ID"); // set Columns Headers


        this->readFile();
     for(unsigned int i = 0; i < this->allBookings.size(); i ++){
                ui->tableWidget->insertRow(ui->tableWidget->rowCount());
                QString q= QString::number(this->allBookings.at(i)->getId());
                ui->tableWidget->setItem(static_cast<int>(i),0, new QTableWidgetItem(q));
                q = QString::number(this->allBookings.at(i)->getPrice());
                ui->tableWidget->setItem(static_cast<int>(i),1, new QTableWidgetItem(q));

                q  = QString::fromStdString( this->findCustomer(this->findTravel(this->allBookings.at(i)->getTravelID())->getCustomerID())->getName());


                ui->tableWidget->setItem(static_cast<int>(i),2, new QTableWidgetItem(q));
                q = QString::number(this->allBookings.at(i)->getTravelID());
                ui->tableWidget->setItem(static_cast<int>(i),3, new QTableWidgetItem(q));

        }
        ui->tableWidget->resizeColumnsToContents();
        ui->actionDatei_Einlesen->setEnabled(false);
}
```

at the lines 107 and 108 , newly added data was not show

[image]

Comment: `int a = ui->tableWidget->rowCount();` Seems like you're going past the last row of your table. If you have only one row in your table, the index would be `0`, and `rowCount` would return `1`, which would mean that row in `setItem` would be out of range.

Comment: it's solved ! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's your problem:

```
ui->tableWidget->insertRow(ui->tableWidget->rowCount());
int a = ui->tableWidget->rowCount();
```

You insert a row. That increases the result of rowCount().
Then you use the *new* rowCount() as the row where your items should go.

If you do it the other way around, it works:

```
int a = ui->tableWidget->rowCount();
ui->tableWidget->insertRow(ui->tableWidget->rowCount());
```

or simply

```
int a = ui->tableWidget->rowCount();
ui->tableWidget->setRowCount(a+1);
// ...
```

Comment: It's worked. I dk why have i not seen the problem before .  Thanks a lot for your help